How to debug chrome extension with VSCode?
I followed the documentation on how to debug the web apps with the existing instance or the new instance of chrome with remote debugging port configured and it works fine. I have an extension which has both background script as well as content script. Since the content script is part of website, VSCode debugger works fine with that. I am not able to get the VSCode debugger working with the extension code. Any help would be appreciated

Try Debug Chrome Extensions with Visual Studio Code
